# $n$-digit natural numbers having a total sum of digits divisible by $5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many $n$-digit natural numbers have a total sum of digits divisible by $5$?
I think this problem can be re-stated as:
How many roots are there for the following equation:
$x_1+x_2+...+x_n\equiv{0}\pmod{5}$ , ($0\leq x_i\leq 9$)

Comment: It seems that the answer is $18\cdot 10^{N-2}$ for $N\ge 2$, but I have no proof yet.

Comment: @Peter Would you please explain more?

Comment: I only calculated some values with PARI/GP.

Comment: I'm looking forward for a mathematical analysis.

Comment: @Peter For induction we should guess some formula first

Comment: I guessed a formula, but induction is not needed anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x_1$ has 9 choices  , and $x_2,x_3 \cdots x_{n-1}$ have 10 choices each , now whatever be the numbers we can choose $x_n$ such that their sum is divisible by $5$ and you will have two choices for that , i.e $$x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_{n-1} \equiv{y}\pmod 5$$ then $$x_n\equiv{1-y}\pmod 5$$ 
thus your total numbers become $9.10^{n-2}.2=18.10^{n-2}$
for example if your remainder for $n-1$ terms is $4$ then you can either choose $6$ or $1$ as your last number.

Comment: Where does $2$ in your formula come from?

Comment: there are 2 digits that have same mod to 5 , 1&6 2&7 3&8 4&9 5&0 these are 5 pairs giving 5 different mods possible thus 2 digits for the last place

Comment: Nice answer! +1 . This answer also shows that the remainders $0,1,2,3,4$ occur equally often. For $N=1$, we have $1$ number, unless we allow $0$, then we have $2$ numbers.